# how to stop service on local host through command

Tags: ubuntu

I have started a server on local host. It can be accessed by the local clients well. But I have made some changes it this server. I want to end the server and want to re start it again so that the new changes I can see. I crossed the ubuntu terminal from where I initiated the server but still its running. Please tell me how to stop it.

Comment: What server have you started? Please provide what server, and commands you've used to start it.

Comment: I started a service name ldf-server through command ldf-server config.json 5000 4 at port 5000.